# C++ WinApi ReadOnly Multiline EditBox weird behavior

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I created a readonly multiline editbox using this code:

```
CreateWindow(L"EDIT", NULL,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | ES_READONLY,
        5, 60, 590, 180,
        hWnd, (HMENU)500, hInst, 0);
```

I added some text and changed it's font:

```
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWnd, 500), WM_SETFONT, WPARAM(hFont), TRUE);
SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hWnd, 500), L"blah blah blahhh\r\n");
```

Then under `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` (not `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` because it is readonly) I changed it's background and text color:

```
if ((HWND)lParam == GetDlgItem(hWnd, 500) ) {
    SetBkMode((HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT);
    SetTextColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(255, 255, 255));
    return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
}
```

The problem is when I highlight or ever just click the text inside this editbox two things happen:

1. the font weight changes to bold and
2. the highlighted text stay highlighted where ever I click

Is there anything wrong or missing in my code?

Comment: When you return NULL_BRUSH the edit control does not erase the background.  So the text gets repainted on top of existing pixels.  That makes the anti-aliasing pixels at the edges of the glyphs darker.  Yes, looks like it makes it bold.  Blobby is the more appropriate term.  If you minimize and restore the window then it looks good again, the background got repainted.

Comment: If you want a white background, return a white brush.

Comment: Yes, you re right. When I minimize and restore the window, its ok again. But, is there anything I can do to solve this?

Comment: Well, of course, don't return NULL_BRUSH.  Do use any think please :)  Sorry, that was too good to pass up.

Comment: I tried `return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(RGB(40,40,40));` but it didn't work

Comment: @HansPassant "anythinK" I just noticed it :)

Comment: Please don't just downvote. Explain why. Thanks

Comment: Why do you assume that [GetStockObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144925.aspx) expects an RGB-value?

Comment: Ok, I changed to `return (LRESULT)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(40, 40, 40));` and it worked :)

Comment: Congrats. Now you have a resource leak.

Comment: @IInspectable So, what's the correct code?

Comment: `static HBRUSH hbrBkgnd = ::CreateSolidBrush(RGB(40, 40, 40)); return (LRESULT)hbrBkgnd`, for example. You really need to read a book. I'd recommend Charles Petzold's [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](http://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X).

Comment: @IInspectable And I use the same brush for every control I want to change it's background color?

Comment: You can use the same brush for multiple controls. The only requirement is, that the brush object outlives the control. A variable with static storage duration (whose referenced data never gets destroyed) meets this requirement.